# How to center NSSegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nssegmentedcontrol

I've added an NSSegmentedControl to a pane on an horizontal split view on a normal window. I thought that adjusting the springs would make the segmented control centre itself automatically, but it doesn't. How can keep it centred?

I was told to add an observer for when the parent view's frame changes, and manually adjust the position of the centered view, but I've no idea how to go about that.

Any ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout you describe sounds totally plausible in IB.

Just testing it out, I dropped a segmented control in one of the views in a split view, and it stays centered, so I'm sure there's just a configuration issue.

Be sure that:

1. Your split view is set to stay centered and resize appropriately with the window as appropriate (just to make sure the behaviour you're seeing is not related to the segmented control's container not resizing properly).
2. You position your segmented control dead centre, and then leave all 3 horizontal "springs" unclicked (ie: no left anchoring, no right anchoring, no horizontal growing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's been "fixed" in recent OS versions, but if I recall correctly, NSSegmentedControl does a -sizeToFit each time segments change. If the control isn't changing at all, Jarrett's instructions should work.